# How can I represent a 5-tuple in RDF?

Tags: rdf

In RDF I have seen examples like

```
John | Is a Friend of | James
James | Is a friend of | Jill
Jill | Likes | Snowboarding
Snowboarding | Is a | Sport
```

But if something happened in a model which is described by a 5-tuple called

```
{Subject, Event, Beneficiary, Time, Place}
```

For Example:

```
"John met Thomas yesterday in garden"
```

5-tuple

```
John - Subject
met - Event
Thomas - Beneficiary
yesterday - Time
in garden - Place
```

How can it be represented in RDF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of **n-ary relationships**. They are typically modeled in RDF with the help of an extra node, which may be a blank node (but does not necessarily have to).

The **W3C** *Semantic Web Best Practices and Deployment Working Group* has **published [a note on n-ary relationships in RDF](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/)**.

One of many ways to express your example in RDF could look like

```
ex:John ex:hasMeeting 
    [ a ex:Meeting;
      ex:beneficiary ex:Thomas;
      ex:date ex:Yesterday;
      ex:place ex:Garden.
    ] .
```

This solution uses a blank node (abbreviated with `[]` in turtle syntax) and imaginary individuals and properties in the `ex:` namespace.