# Representing complicated sentences using RDF syntax

Tags: rdf, semantic-web

I am new to RDF and I have one question about RDF.

With some simple sentence like : "Ann studies Math", there's no problem to represent it using RDF.

But with more complicated sentences such as: "**Mr Parker teaches Machine Learning and uses the book named ML-for-newbie**", I mean Mr Parker uses that book to prepare his lectures. There're 3 objects : ***Mr Parker, Machine Learning, ML-for-newbie***; 2 predicates: ***teach, use***. So how to represent this sentence in RDF? As I know, one RDF statement is like Subject --predicate--> Object, and the 3 objects and 2 predicates make me confused :(

Plz Help, thanks!

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820657/how-can-i-represent-a-5-tuple-in-rdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, you could either decompose these sentences in 3 RDF statements or use a [blank node](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blank_node).

Examples of decomposition, the course has its own URI (`:Course999`):

```
:Mr_Parker    :teaches    :Course999 .
:Course999    :courseName    "Machine Learning" .
:Course999    :hasSupportBook    "ML-for-newbies" .
```

With anonymous nodes (blank node `_:b1`), it's the same principle but the course is not explicitly captured:

```
:Mr_Parker    :teaches    _:b1 .
_:b1    :courseName    "Machine Learning" .
_:b1    :hasSupportBook    "ML-for-newbies" .
```

Now as mentioned in the comments, the string "ML-for-newbies" is actually not a book, it just represent the title of the book. So you could add more triples to capture extra information about this item (like the author of this book for instance). You can think of re-using already developed vocabulary for this task (like the Dublin Core):

```
:Mr_Parker    :teaches    _:b1 .
_:b1    :hasSupportBook    :book2 .
:book2    dcterms:title    "ML-for-newbies" .
:book2    dcterms:creator    "John Smith" .
```

... and then here the string represent just the name of the author but not the author itself (like for the book), so you could expand your triples even more by representing this entity type too if needed.

Comment: Good answer, but a string isn't a book. You should add another resource, :book123 or somesuch, which has "ML for Newbies" as a title, and can then have an author, isbn, etc, as well.

Comment: Thank you @loopasam, I think the 2nd manner is more suitable (and i did think about that). Thanks again :)

Comment: Good point from Ian: Here it's an over-simplistic representation just to get you started, then you can increase the level of detail of the things you want to represent in a similar fashion. I add it to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is good and has examples, but it's worth having a look at the W3C's Working Group Note [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/) that discusses these representation issues.  The approach in the accepted answer is [Pattern 1: introducing a new class for a relation](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/#pattern1) in that note.  There's also a [Pattern 2: Using lists for arguments in a relation](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/#pattern2), but that feels clumsier, and I don't think as many people take that approach.

Comment: Hi @Joshua Taylor , how to represent a statement like "**If one student has at least 10 dogs, then he has also 10 cats**" using owl???

Comment: @Songokute That's really a unrelated question and should be asked as such (not in the comments), but that's fairly basic OWL:  `(Student and hasPet min 10 Dog) subClassOf (hasPet min 10 Cat)`.

Comment: Thank you, I did ask a new question about this. :) In your case: `(X) subClassOf (Y)`, then X and Y are anonymous or named classes (I wonder how to name those classes if they have their name...)?